# Trying to print out data found by regular expressions that is sent to 2 different arrays print out in a specific order

Tags: php, html, regex

I have an `HTML` file that I need to pull certain data from. I'm using regex which seems simple enough. I have 2 types of data that I need to pull. I need dates and transactions. I want to print out all transactions for a specific date. But due to the date number being unnumbered as well as the transactions. I don't know how to iterate through both.

I have honestly been scratching my head over this for a few hours and couldn't get to a solution.

```
$balpage=curl_exec($ch);

for($i=0;$i<count(  );$i++){
  if(preg_match('#<\s*?strong\b[^>]*>(.*?) 
  </strong\b[^>]*>#s',$balpage)==1){

    preg_match('#<\s*?strong\b[^>]*>(.*?) 
    </strong\b[^>]*>#s',$balpage,$date);

    preg_match('#\<span class=\"issecureoff\"\>(.+?)\ 
 <\/span\>#s',$balpage,$transactions);


print_r($date[1][$i]);
print_r($transactions[1][$i]);
}
```

The code you see is very incomplete and not even working, but I'm just putting out what it kinda should maybe look like? Sorry I'm really new at this so if you code gurus could help me, that would be awesome.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Wy6qx2d1 here is the html if you need it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that, you might just want to use `preg_match_all`, yet we can slightly modify our expression too:

```
<\s*strong[^>]*>(.*?)<\/strong[^>]*>|<span class="issecureoff">(.+?)<\/span>
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/<\s*strong[^>]*>(.*?)<\/strong[^>]*>|<span class="issecureoff">(.+?)<\/span>/m';
$str = '<i class="uk-icon-calendar"></i><strong>2019.06.04</strong></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                         09:35
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        орлого
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">0.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="text-green uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">5,000.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                        <img src="Content/img/arrow_up.png" width="8"></td>

                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">5,000.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap uk-text-right">                 </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                         09:35
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Ухаалаг мэдээ үйлчилгээний хураамж
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">5,000.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="text-red uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">-50.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                        <img src="Content/img/arrown_down.png" width="8"></td>

                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">4,950.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap uk-text-right">                 </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="6" class="text-12 letter-space-1"><i class="uk-icon-calendar"></i><strong>2019.06.14</strong></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                         11:00
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        batidert
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">4,950.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="text-green uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">50,000.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                        <img src="Content/img/arrow_up.png" width="8"></td>

                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap">
                                        <span class="issecureoff">54,950.00</span>
                                        <span class="issecureon">*</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="text-16 uk-text-nowrap uk-text-right">       5028604392</td>
                                </tr>
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### Output

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<strong>2019.06.04</strong>"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2019.06.04"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(37) "<span class="issecureoff">0.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(4) "0.00"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "<span class="issecureoff">5,000.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "5,000.00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "<span class="issecureoff">5,000.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "5,000.00"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "<span class="issecureoff">5,000.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "5,000.00"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(39) "<span class="issecureoff">-50.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(6) "-50.00"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "<span class="issecureoff">4,950.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "4,950.00"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(27) "<strong>2019.06.14</strong>"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "2019.06.14"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(41) "<span class="issecureoff">4,950.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(8) "4,950.00"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "<span class="issecureoff">50,000.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(9) "50,000.00"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(42) "<span class="issecureoff">54,950.00</span>"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(9) "54,950.00"
  }
}
```

#### [Please see the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/APMpwT/1/)

Comment: Thank for the revision of my expression. but what i want to find out is i need to have the date associate with that dates transaction. You probably could see the amounts between the tags span issecureoff. So i need to have the date and then the transactions and then date for the next day and so on.

Comment: My god. You just saved me hours of headache. Thank youu soooo much. I wish i can upvote but cant cause my rep is lower than 15. Ill come back and upvote when i get high rep

Comment: @Desmond - You can and should accept the answer if you found it to be accurate and helpful.  You can do so by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: @Emma So im working with a similar issue but i have (div style="width:100%;overflow:hidden;) as the date and (td align="right") as the transaction. I cant seem to get the regex working. Any clues?